# Problemas con las ñ al codificar en sha256

Tags: c#, nodejs, utf-8, codificación, ascii

tengo un problema al consumir un WebService en C#, la siguiente funcion de c# crea un token que recibe el WS

```
 SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
 byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("algun texto"));
 StringBuilder strbHash = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (byte b in hash)
    strbHash.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
 return strbHash.ToString();

//algun texto = arana
//token = 8a4f30adac3a33ba52abae8a51a784175d851edb5e7d65ecb0b240902ef5ca34

//algun texto = araña
//token = f686964edf1e0feea8a50cd1352efa94196d6f19bd22ff7abad706ff15852d2e
```

ahora esto con nodejs

```
crypto.createHash('sha256').update('algun texto').digest('hex');

//algun texto = arana
//token = 8a4f30adac3a33ba52abae8a51a784175d851edb5e7d65ecb0b240902ef5ca34

//algun texto = araña
//token = ca0cb8ad064b08a36b61e31878b94fb883a55b5d16f94a92728cb631a3cdb4b5
```

como podran ver el token solo difiere cuando hay una 'Ñ', ningun otro carácter altera mi token, pero necesito usar la 'Ñ'.

como puedo evitar esa diferencia?

Comment: Reemplaza `Encoding.ASCII` por `Encoding.Unicode`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La función [hash.update](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_inputencoding) que estás utilizando asume que la codificación (*encoding*) del texto es `utf-8` a menos que especifiques el segundo parámetro. En el código C# estás leyendo los caracteres como `ascii`, es por esto la discrepancia. Lo que puedes hacer en node:

```
crypto.createHash('sha256').update('algun texto', 'ascii').digest('hex');
```

fíjate que ahora le pasas 2 parámetros a update, el texto y la codificación.

Otra alternativa es que cambies la codificación en C#, es decir que

```
hashstring.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("algun texto"));
```

En resumen, haz que la representación binaria del texto sea la misma en ambos lados.

Comment: Interesante. Yo había sugerido `Encoding.Unicode` puesto que las cadenas en JavaScript se encodean utilizando UTF-16. No obstante la librería crypto de node convierte las cadenas UTF-16 a UTF-8 antes de hacer el cálculo byte por byte. Efectivamente la respuesta correcta en C# es utilizar `Encoding.UTF8`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es por que nodejs trata las cadenas en UTF-16 y en el código c# lo tratas en ASCII, la ñ es un carácter de ASCII EXTENDIDO  y doble byte en UTF-16. Por eso te dan distinto hash

Comment: En js todas las cadenas de textos se codifican en UTF-16. No UTF-8. Pero sí efectivamente el problema es el encoding.

Comment: Correcto, corrijo respuesta. Gracias por la aclaración